# saving/exporting data from a custom visual studio desktop application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Situation: I'm trying to export data from my application into a format that can then be shared with other users of the same application which can then be edited by those users within the application.

What is the application? It is an image assembling application that takes other images and puts them together using a collection of other variables, Arrays, Ints, Booleans, and such. then exports the compiled image as a .PNG.

Built In: C# Visual Studio 2019, Windows Forms Application .NET Framework

Question: How do I get all of the Data and Images into a shareable folder/file or something that I can then send/load into someone else's instance of my application for further editing?

I have consulted Google and YouTube the masters of random knowledge but have come up with no results that suit my request, perhaps I am using the wrong keywords or something but any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: Should the images be also saved in the file or only referenced?

Comment: preferably saved into the file.

Comment: Then you might consider to use a zip archive to save all image files and everything else like variables could be saved as one file formated as a json or xml string. You might also want to use a different file extension for the resulting zip archive.

Comment: do you have a link to a guide describing the process? I'm not very familiar with this process.

Comment: Take a look at the [`ZipAtchive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-5.0) class to for creating zip files

Comment: Using the JSON system from newtonsoft.Json add-in or whatever its called, helped me get all of the array data set up in a useable way probably not optimal but useable. Now I'm working on creating a project folder to store all other data which should be much easier than learning the JSON system.

Comment: Using json in c# is not that hard. You basically just need a proper class model for your data and the work to serialize it is done by the newtonsoft json serializer.